# Windows 10 Prof Ubuntu <mount> command: Does not work to attach NFS Server resources

Tags: mount, windows-10, nfs, client

I cannot get the  command to work (completes successfully but nothing is there inside the mtpt) in Windows 10 Pro in a Ubuntu window as of 1/26/2018.  I enabled NFS client services, and issued  to make sure I have the latest  command.
     Has Microsoft disabled this function or does it only work on Win 10 Enterprise?  Win 1 pro Native NFS client works great.
     Thank you for any info!

~Charlie

Comment: This sounds like it is actually a request for help with Windows 10. Consider using http://answers.microsoft.com instead.